# uncaught syntaxerror unexpected identifier at jquery ajax url

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have ajax code like this

```
$.ajax({
            url: "AJAX_POST_URL",
            type: "POST",
            data: {commentId:commentId,commentText:commentText},
            dataType : 'json'
            success: function(data)
            {
                if(data.error=='false'){
                    $('comment'+commentId).html(commentText);
                }
            },
});
```

i am facing this error "uncaught syntaxerror unexpected identifier" at url line.

please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: try with absolute path for url than relative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just pointed out the syntax error that you made as comment lines

Try,

```
$.ajax({
    url: "AJAX_POST_URL",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        commentId: commentId,
        commentText: commentText
    },
    dataType: 'json',  //Missed a comma over here
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.error == 'false') {
            $('comment' + commentId).html(commentText);
        }
    }  //placed an unncessary comma over here
});
```

Comment: @Srinu glad to help..!  and also take care `$('comment' + commentId)` of this line.. whether you are going to use `#` or `.` before comment..!

Answer (score 1):

Use **'#'** before comment selector. Also add **','** before success and remove unnecessary **','** after success.

```
$.ajax({
      url: "AJAX_POST_URL",
      type: "POST",
      data: {commentId:commentId,commentText:commentText},
      dataType : 'json',
      success: function(data)
      {
       if(data.error=='false'){
          $('#comment'+commentId).html(commentText);
       }
     }
 });
```

Comment: Thank you RGS for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'AJAX_POST_URL',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {commentId:commentId,commentText:commentText},
        dataType : 'json'
        }).success(function(data)
        {
            if(data.error=='false'){
                $('comment'+commentId).html(commentText);
            }
        }).error(function () {
              alert("Something went wrong");
          });
```